# Random numpy array in order

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

I have a random sampling method as below:

```
def costum_random_sample(size):
    randomList = []
    counter = 0
    last_n = -1
    while(size != counter):
        n = random.random()
        if abs(n - last_n) < 0.05:
            continue
        else:
            randomList.append(n)
            counter += 1
            last_n = n

    return np.array(randomList)
```

The result is an array([0.50146945, 0.17442673, 0.60011469, 0.13501798]) like this. Now, I want to change it to make it resulted in order likes array in ascending order. Sort() doesn't work in this case since it change the order of my array after it is generated, and the logic between each number is changed. I want it random the number in list in order, by that way it could keep the logic in the number sequence. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are shortish, you can simply generate the whole array, sort it, and reject it and regenerate as long as the constraint is violated.

```
bad = True
while bad:
    arr = np.sort(np.random.rand(size))
    bad = np.any(np.ediff1d(arr) < 0.05)
```

If `size` is too big, the conflicts will be too plentiful, and this will take forever, so only use it if there is a reasonable chance a conformant array will be generated randomly. Note that if `size > 20` there is no array that will fit the criteria, turning this into an infinite loop.

Another approach would be to generate and sort the array as above, find the non-conformant element pairs, then nudge the array elements by increasing the distance between the non-comformant pairs and evenly subtracting this difference from other places. This can't get stuck in an infinite loop, but has a bit more math, and bends the uniform distribution (though I couldn't tell you how much).

**EDIT** After thinking a bit, there's a much better way. Basically, you need a spaced array, where there's a fixed spacer and a little bit of extra randomness between each element:

```
random start space
[element1]
0.05 spacer
some more space
[element2]
0.05 spacer
some more space
[element3]
random end space
```

All the space needs to add up to 1. However, some of that space is fixed (`(size - 1) * 0.05`); so if we take out the fixed spacers, we have our "space budget" to distribute between our start, end and random space. So we generate random space and then punch it a bit so it sums up to our space budget. Then add in the fixed spacers, and cumulative sum will give us the final array (and an extra `1.0` at the end, which we chop off).

```
space_budget = 1 - (size - 1) * 0.05
space = np.random.rand(size + 1)
space *= space_budget / np.sum(space)
space[1:-1] += 0.05
arr = np.cumsum(space)[:-1]
```

For `size = 21`, you get exactly one solution every time, as `space_budget` is zero. For larger `size`, you start bursting out of the 0...1 range as it's mathematically impossible to stuff more than 21 0.05 spacers into that interval.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Actually I tried some ways, but it stuck in infinite loop since my array has 20 elements

Comment: oh, cool. I got your idea. It looks better than what I'm doing now. I will try it.